# Можно ли считать синонимом объявления этих функций?

Tags: php

```
$str = 'Какая-то строка';

// Вариант со ссылкой use на переменную $str
    $foo = function ($sep) use ($str) {
    $out = $sep . $str . $sep;
    return $out;
};

// Вариант с объявлением переменной $str глобальной
$foo = function ($sep) {
    global $str;
    return $sep . $str . $sep;
};

echo $foo('~');
```

Результат их работы идентичный. Я так понимаю, что оператор use передаёт в область видимости функции переменную $str. Оператор global внутри функции выполняет то же, что и use - значит эти два объявления можно считать синонимами?

Comment: Глобальные переменные зло так что лучше юзе. Да и Глобал изменит переменную

Comment: наверное нет, если я не путаю. При global будет захват одного экземпляра, а use захватит контекст и например в цикле будет захват разных $str

Comment: @vitidev , если я вас правильно понял, при использовании  в цикле переменной $str , полученной с помощью use , эффект будет аналогичным, как и со статической (static) переменной? Иначе говоря, я смогу только читать данные из $str,  но изменять их нет?

Comment: Я могу путать как там в пхп ибо они все делают по своему, но...global захватывает переменную из глобальной области видимости. use захватывает из локальной области видимости. глобальная видимость одна, а локальная видимость не одна. Например обернуть все это циклом где $str  присваивать при каждой итерации новое значение - эта новая переменная и будет захвачена. В случае с global же по идее будет всегда одна и та же.
это все надо проверять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете анонимные функции, также известные как замыкания (closures), которые позволяют создавать функции, не имеющие определенных имен.

Замыкания могут также наследовать переменные из родительской области видимости. Любая подобная переменная должна быть объявлена в конструкции use. Изменения внутри не будут отражаться на переменной из родительской области видимости, чтобы изменять переменную внутри и отражать изменения в родительскую область необходимо добавить перед началом &, тогда переменная будет передана по ссылке.

```
$foo = function ($sep) use (&$str) {
    $out = $sep . $str . $sep;
    return $out;
};
```

Конструкция global $a говорит о том, что переменная $а является глобальной, т. е. является синонимом глобальной $а и изменения внутри функции будут отражены в глобальную область видимости. После определения переменных через global все ссылки на любую из этих переменных будут указывать на их глобальную версию.

Таким образом иструкция global создает ссылку на массив $GLOBALS, т.о. эти две записи будут эквивалентны:

```
function test() { 
global $a; 
$а = 10; 
} 

function test() { 
$а = &$GLOBALS['a']; 
$а = 10; 
}
```

Массив $GLOBALS доступен из любого места в программе — в том числе и из тела функции, и его не нужно никак дополнительно объявлять.

По вашему вопросу, могу сказать, то что вы определяете функции двумя способами является совершенно одинаковым. Вы просто меняете способ передачи параметров в функцию.

*P.S. Чрезмерное определение глобальных переменных грозит усложнением поиска ошибок в программе. Это реальный способ довести до сумасшествия программиста, который будет потом разбирать твою программу.*

Comment: благодарю за исчерпывающий ответ! )

Comment: @Эдуард но стоит вам этот код внести в метод класса и функции станут полностью  разными. use будет захватывать ближайший контекст, а global будет захватывать переменные определенные вне класса.

Comment: @vitidev , по поводу использования в ооп мне было ясно, интересовало поведение функций именно в процедурном стиле. Спасибо )

Comment: @Эдуард и в процедурном (нет никаких классов), но сли этот коду будет внутри цикла то будет разный результат.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю по коду ниже Вам должно стать понятно, что замыкания используют копии значения переменных на момент объявления (случай без &), а глобал использует ссылку на последнюю версию. Передача по ссылке в замыкание, эквиваленто использованию global

```
<?php

$d = 0; 

$closure = function() use($d){ 
  return $d; 
};

$d = 2;

echo $closure(); // выведет 0 

function display(){
  global $d; // 
  return $d;
}

$d = 6;

echo display(); // выведет 6
```